# jquery DataTables plugin: Server-side data, use length menu and show "All" with -1?

Tags: jquery, datatables

In the length menu example, we see the options set as follows: 
http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html

```
 $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
  });
```

Yet when I try this approach server-side, it fails when selecting "All". 
Has anyone run across this issue before or familiar with 
how to handle this scenario?

Comment: My question has been answered in a manner of sorts on the datatbles forum. http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=3959&page=1#Comment_16445

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered on the datatables forum.

The "-1" can be thought of as a "dummy" value 
that needs to be processed server-side. 
(pseudo-code: if @numberofrows = -1, then select all)

http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=3959&page=1#Comment_16445

Answer (score 1):

it will be better if you post your question in dataTable forum...there you will get more response..here is link for that [DataTable Forum](http://datatables.net/forums/)

you can try something like this also...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
      "oLanguage": {
                   "sLengthMenu": 'Display <select><option value="10">10</option>
                                                   <option value="20">20</option>
                                                   <option value="30">30</option>
                                                   <option value="40">40</option>
                                                   <option value="50">50</option>
                                                   <option value="-1">All</option>
                                   </select> records'
                  }
               } );
            } );
```

Comment: Yes, I posted a message about the same time on the DataTables forum, but I also posted here, because it's hard to tell if as many people jump in on the datatables forum. The option you provide above leaves the same problem as I had: i.e., the "-1" has to be handled in the server scripting language. http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=3959&page=1#Comment_16445